# How would one do an inner join in linq to entities?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Given two tables, customer and orders, how would one do a linq query to entities to find any customers with open invoices started before a certain date?

Answer (score 1):

VB.net

```
Dim query = _
    From customer In customers _
    From order In orders _
    Where customer.CustomerID = order.Customer.CustomerID _
    And order.OrderDate <=  dtOrderDate _
    And order.IsOpen = True _
    Select New With _
    { _
        CustomerID = customer.CustomerID, _
        OrderID = order.SalesOrderID, _
        Total = order.TotalDue _
    }
```

I modified the code from the [Query Expression Syntax Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738447.aspx)

I got there from the [Linq to entites site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx)